# Ajax post issue with smarty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have script using smarty engine.

I just tried to use ajax post to get some data from page.

The javascript function as following:

```
function getTime(val,id) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '{$GLOBALS.site_url}/check_time/',
    data:'GetDate='+val + '&Jobid='+id,
    success: function(data){
            alert(data);                
    }
});
```

}

the alert show me (3 small squares) I don't know what dose mean !

Comment: Those are probably characters outside of the character set your browser is using, which is why they're being displayed as the squares instead. You might want to use your browser's debug functions to look at the return data, as that may render them correctly.

Comment: The 3 small squares are characters which your browser cannot display. Maybe it is the [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: What are you expecting to see? As @AdrianWragg pointed out try using Chrome Dev Tools Network panel to debug your issue. Also why are `getting` data via `POST`?

Comment: The php page contain only one word, but still I get the same squares.